# DSolve subject to

Tags: differential-equations

I want to compute two differential equations with subject to conditions. My solution:

```
eqn1 = x1'[t] + x2[t] == (-3/10)*x1[t];
eqn2 = x1[t] - x2'[t] == 1;
subjectto = {x1[0] == 1/2, x2[0] == 0};

DSolve[{eqn1, eqn2}, subjectto, {x, t}]
```

But I got an error `x1[0]==1/2 cannot be used as a function.` What do I do wrong, please?

Comment: There's no `x` in your equation, why do you even expect the code will work? Please calm down, check the document of `DSolve` carefully by pressing F1. (If you're using Wolfram engine, then check the online document: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html ) Get used to reading the document that's well-written and suitable for self-learning, this is the first thing a beginner should learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DSolve[Join[{eqn1, eqn2}, subjectto], {x1, x2}, t]

(* {{x1 -> Function[{t}, 
    1/782 E^(-3 t/
      20) (-391 Cos[(Sqrt[391] t)/20] + 
       782 E^(3 t/20) Cos[(Sqrt[391] t)/20]^2 - 
       9 Sqrt[391] Sin[(Sqrt[391] t)/20] + 
       782 E^(3 t/20) Sin[(Sqrt[391] t)/20]^2)], 
  x2 -> Function[{t}, -(1/3910)
     E^(-3 t/20) (-1173 Cos[(Sqrt[391] t)/20] + 
        1173 E^(3 t/20) Cos[(Sqrt[391] t)/20]^2 + 
        91 Sqrt[391] Sin[(Sqrt[391] t)/20] + 
        1173 E^(3 t/20) Sin[(Sqrt[391] t)/20]^2)]}}  *)
```

Have fun!